# .Net Core SonarQube - Make sure the logger's configuration is safe

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, sonarqube, serilog

I have the following code to log errors into application insights. I use SeriLog and enrich it with a property

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", "MyDashboard").
WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(builder.Configuration
.GetConnectionString("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"), new TraceTelemetryConverter())
.CreateLogger();
```

SonarQube keeps flagging this line asking to make the logger's configuration safe.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: You need to use WriteTo.ApplicationInsights() method in order to make the logger's configuration safe.

From your code I can be see that the `CreateLogger() `method is used to create a logger with any configuration. That means it is possible to create a logger that is configured to write sensitive information to the log.

Answer (score 1):

Now coming back to the solution you need to take the overload of `WriteTo.ApplicationInsights()`. include the overload version of the method which has `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Configuration.ApplicationInsightsConfiguration` object as its second parameter.

```
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights;
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", "MyDashboard")
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"), new ApplicationInsightsConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetTelemetryConverter(new TraceTelemetryConverter())
        .DisableSensitiveInformationLogging()
        .Build())
    .CreateLogger();
```

the code will create a logger that will write telemetry to Application Insights using the `TraceTelemetryConverter` and also the `DisableSensitiveInformationLogging()` method instructs the logger not to log any sensitive information, and there by resolving your SonarQube warning.

Comment: Which nuget package contains `ApplicationInsightsConfigurationBuilder` , it is showing as undefined.

Comment: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` - Also see the Application Insights documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` is already installed. Still it is showing as undefined.